# Understanding absolute and relative imports

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a function from a file which is in another module but keep getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I have seen lots of articles saying do absolute instead of relative imports but then get the error

```
ImportError: No module named app.main.events
```

My file structure

```
\_ dir
    \_ __init__.py
    \_ app
        \_ main
            \_ __init__.py
            \_ events.py
        \_ game
            \_ __init__.py
            \_ run.py
```

events.py

```
def my_function():
    do something....
```

run.py

```
from ..main.events import my_function
# returns
Attempted relative import in non-package

from app.main.events import my_function
# returns
No module named app.main.events
```

I can't see where im going wrong... It's probably something so simple.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative imports are fine as long as you use them within a package and are explicit, e.g `from . import foo`. What the articles are saying is bad is when you `import foo` and rely on a file called foo.py being in the same directory.

If you're executing `python run.py` directly, the interpreter has no idea that run.py is part of a larger package. You either need to run it as a module using `python -m run.main`, or preferably (in my opinion) set up an [entry point](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) in your setup.py.

Also can't remember if it's necessary or not, but you may be missing an __init__.py in your `app` subdirectory.